# React Redux Url Change Events / Architecture

Tags: reactjs, events, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm building an application with React. If someone wants to search the following happens:

1. State is updated: this.props.Address.selectedAddress
2. Click on a search button the search event is trigger AND my URL is changed:

   ```
   this.props.handleSearch(address);
   let city = format_city(this.props.Address.selectedAddress);
   browserHistory.push('/searchfor/'+city);
   ```

That works fine. Now I would like that a search event is also triggered if someone puts a new url in the application. What I did so far:

```
class ResultsList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = browserHistory.listen( (location) =>  {
        console.log('route changes');
        if (this.selectedAdressNOTMatchUrl()){
            this.handelAdressSearch()
        }

    });

}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();

}
```

Now the problem that the click event changes the url and the result list component thinks it have to handle this event: triggering search and updateting selectedAddress.

I really think it is a bad design how I have done it. Of course I could add a timestamp or something like this to figure out if browserHistory.push('/searchfor/'+city); happend right before the url change event is fired, but that is a bit ugly.

Every idea is appreciated!

Here is my setup:

```
export const store = createStore(
reducers,
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
compose(
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        promiseMiddleware()),
    autoRehydrate()
)
);

const persistor = persistStore(store, {storage: localForage});
render(
<Provider store={store} persistor={persistor}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/searchfor/:city" component={Suche}/>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
```

PS: One more remark
I tried react-router-redux. It saves the url state. BUT it doese not solve the issue. If for example I enter a new url. Then the Event LOCATION_CHANGE is fired. BUT short after that, my persist/REHYDRATE event is fired. So that the url changes back. That makes the behavior even worse...

PPS: To make it more clear. Everything works fine. I want to add one more feature. If the users enters a new url himself, then the application should handle this the same way if he clicked on the search button. BUT it seems a bid of hard, since in that case in my application the rehydrate event is fired...

Comment: What version of React Router are you using? (see package.json)

Comment: I'm using the version 2.8.1. Here is a part of my config: 
    "pg-promise": "^5.6.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
    "react-debounce-input": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^4.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-responsive": "^1.2.7",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.5.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"

Comment: When is the result (based on the search) for the ResultList fetched? In the `this.props.handleSearch(address);` ?

Comment: I hope I understood you correct. this.props.handleSearch(address); Is triggered if someone clicks on search and hits enter like in google. Then few things happens. 1) url is pushed / updated based on selectedAddress (the users input)  2) old results are cleared 3) the input of the user that is stored in  selectedAddress is used to make a request to the server 4) the new results are saved and displayed by the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how redux-persist ("rehydrating") works so maybe I'm missing something crucial.. But I'm thinking it could be possible to solve your issue through connecting your `ResultsList` component to Redux so that it passes the react-router url-parameter to it, something like this

```js
// ownProps is be the props passed down from the Route, including path params
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
     searchTerm: ownProps.city,  // the url param
     results: state.searchResults // after a manual url entry this will be undefined

  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
     handleSearch: searchTerm => dispatch(searchAction(searchTerm)) 
    };
};
```

(That kind of code should be possible [according to these docs here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html#containersvisibletodolistjs))

Then, inside the `ResultsList`, you could initiate the search.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const {searchTerm, handleSearch} this.props;

     handleSearch(searchTerm);
  }
}

render() {
  const {results} = this.props;
  return !results ?
    <p>Loading..</p> : 
    <div>
     { results.map(renderResultItem) }
    </div>
}
```

That way the component would not have to care if the URL-param came from a manually entered url, or from a programmatically pushed URL from the search page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this version. I'm note sure about rehydrate too. Since things can get ugly if the user enters a new url --> search is triggered and in the same time a rehydrate event is fired, since the users gave the browser the command to reload and persist/Rehydrate tries to get the old state back

Comment: Hope it works out! Maybe the component will show some old data for a few milliseconds right after when the user enters a manual URL, but I would guess that the `componentDidMount` would still run and trigger the new search. But feel free to remove the "Accepted answer" if it turns out this doesn't work.